# How to manipulate the dom using angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node-red

I'm using Node-red and it has a node that uses angular to display html to a page. I'm needing to highlight certain words on the page but no matter what I try, I can't get this to happen.

What happens is i have a string of html that is in msg.payload.

msg.payload looks something like this:

```js
msg.payload: "<html><body>tables and all that good stuff here</body></html>
```

Then in the angular node, that msg.payload goes into this which makes the page display.

```js
<div ng-bind-html="msg.payload">

</div>
```

If i go into the chrome console and do this, i get the result I'm looking for:

```js
Array.prototype.forEach.call(angular.element.find('td'),(value) => {

    value.style.backgroundColor = "yellow"

})
```

The issue is that if i put this in a script tag in the same place where the ng-bind-html happens, it doesn't work. I'm assuming this has something to do with the way angular is being rendered to the page... but I'm a total newbie when it comes to Angular. I was hoping someone on here could point me in the right direction.

Comment: Usually you manipulate DOM with directives. [`$compile`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) could be useful to link DOM with `scope`

Comment: It looks like you're generating the whole `<table>` HTML code server-side, and that you're sending it ready-made to Angular, just for it to display the table. That's not how Angular works. Angular is not jQuery. It's expecting a data structure (an array of rows) that will be used to generate the table in the view, client-side, with `ng-for`. Angular does not manipulate the DOM like jQuery. It generates it from data.